# JSON to struct omitempty PATCH versus POST problem

Tags: json, http, go, struct

I am designing some REST API endpoints in Go. I use structs to define the object that handling in my API methods. These objects are sent as json and are stored in Firebase. Suppose I have the following simple struct:

```
type Person struct {
  Name        string `json:"name" firestore:"name"`
  Gender      string `json:"gender,omitempty" firestore:"gender"`
  Nationality string `json:"nationality,omitempty" firestore:"nationality"`
}
```

And I have the following requirements:

- All fields are required when doing a `GET` request and reading from firebase.
- All fields are required when doing a `POST` request and serializing json body to struct.
- Only the `Name` field is required when doing a `PATCH` request and serializing json body to struct.

What is the cleanest way to do serialization based on the same struct for all the methods? When doing the `GET` request there is no problem, since all the fields are and need to be present in Firebase. However, when I am going to use the `omitempty` tag for json serialization I cannot force the `POST` request to contain all fields and the `PATCH` request to contain only a subset of fields.

Comment: Defining a different model struct for the patch seems clean enough to me. Is there a particular reason for wanting to reuse the same `Person` model? Or you mean that patch may contain also the other fields, but mandate only `Name`?

Comment: I think the "omitempty" tag is only used in case of marshaling a struct to JSON, meaning if you unmarshal an empty json string you will get the struct with Zeroed values. Therefore for GET requests you will get the values populated from the DB or the default ZERO values and you will be serving them downstream. Here the "omitempty" tag comes into play: if it is set, the generated json will not contain the key in the structure if the value is the ZERO value.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [custom marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43160569/custom-json-marshaling) interface or use a 3rd party lib like `https://github.com/json-iterator/go` which support custom json tag

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    jsoniter "github.com/json-iterator/go"
)

type Person struct {
    Name        string `json1:"name" json2:"name"`
    Gender      string `json1:"gender,omitempty" json2:"gender"`
    Nationality string `json1:"nationality,omitempty" json2:"nationality"`
}

func main() {
    p := Person{Name: "bob"}
    json1 := jsoniter.Config{TagKey: "json1"}.Froze()
    json2 := jsoniter.Config{TagKey: "json2"}.Froze()
    b1, _ := json1.Marshal(&p)
    b2, _ := json2.Marshal(&p)
    fmt.Println(string(b1))
    fmt.Println(string(b2))
}
```

output:

```
{"name":"bob"}
{"name":"bob","gender":"","nationality":""}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write a validation function.

```
type Person struct {
    Name        string `json:"name" firestore:"name"`
    Gender      string `json:"gender,omitempty" firestore:"gender"`
    Nationality string `json:"nationality,omitempty" firestore:"nationality"`
}

// ValidatePost validates the struct contains values for all mandatory fields for POST operations
func (p Person) ValidatePost()bool  {
    if p.Name =="" || p.Gender == "" || p.Nationality == ""{
        return false
    }
    return true
}

// ValidatePatch validates the struct contains values for all mandatory fields for PATCH operations
func (p Person) ValidatePatch()bool  {
    if p.Name =="" {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```